# Get the nearby players list using GameCenter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

I am working in an app in which i have to show the nearby player using the gamecenter?
how would i get this?

Comment: What do you mean by a NEARBY player?

Comment: i want to play the game with local wifi players only.

Comment: thanks but i want to have multiplayer game with 7 players and it should be turnbased game so p2p connection does not worth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial here:[multiplayer gaming with game center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_519__multiplayer_gaming_with_game_center.pdf), ([more](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/))

---

[GKMatchmaker Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchmaker_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) has methods like the bellow. You can have a try.

```
– startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:
– stopBrowsingForNearbyPlayers
```

Comment: I've added a tutorial link, try it.

Comment: These methods generate no callbacks for me ? I have tried with and without authenticating local player. Both devices are on same WiFi and have Bluetooth activated and nearyby browsing enabled in Game Center Settings.