# How to invite Players for Turnbased Game using game center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

I am using turnbased match and want to invite players but it doesn't show me any players to invite list.How would i  get the list of player for game cente?

Comment: Can you give us some code to look at, to see where you might be going wrong? I can suggest a tutorial to have a look at, it may give you some ideas http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1 Scroll down to near the bottom where he implements game center.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a similar question [Get the nearby players list using GameCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13510981/1548523) and find an excellent tutorial here:[multiplayer gaming with game center](http://upyun.cocimg.com/upload/g2/2012/10/session_519__multiplayer_gaming_with_game_center.pdf). You can have a look.

Besides,
[GKMatchmaker Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchmaker_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) has methods like the bellow to help you find **nearby** players. You can have a try.

```
– startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:
– stopBrowsingForNearbyPlayers
```